# Proving that $d$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^X$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $\mathbb{R}^X$ denote the set of all functions on a non-empty set $X$ to the real line $\mathbb{R}$, and for $f,g \in \mathbb{R}^X$, let $\displaystyle d(f,g)= \sup_{x \in X } \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|}$. Prove that $(\mathbb{R}^X,d)$ is a metric space.

Attempt: It can be shown that $\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|} \leq \frac{|f(x)-h(x)|}{1+|f(x)-h(x)|}+\frac{|h(x)-g(x)|}{1+|h(x)-g(x)|}$ [using $f(x)=x/(1+x)$ on $[0,\infty)$]. I am comfortable with establishing the inequality. After that $ \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|} \leq \sup [\frac{|h-g|}{1+|h-g|}+\frac{|f-h|}{1+|f-h|}] ≤ \sup \frac{|h-g|}{1+|h-g|}+\sup \frac{|f-h|}{1+|f-h|}$.

Now taking sup over the left hand side establishes

$d(f,g) \leq d(h,g)+d(h,f)$. The other axioms can be verified as well.

Is this valid?

Additional question: Let us consider the set of all real valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Will $\sup|f-g|$ be a valid metric on it?

Comment: I don't get the counterexample, why would there be $\infty \leq \infty + \infty$ ? Also maybe you can consider using $f$ only once :).

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is what valid?

Comment: @copper.hat sorry for making it unclear. I am asking for two things here. 1. Whether the first part where I try to prove that $d$ is a metric is fine or not. 2. Suppose, we take the set of all mappings from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Will $\sup|f-g|$ be a valid metric on it? The supremum in the latter part may assume infinity and the triangle inequality doesn't make much sense, that's what I am asking to verify.

Comment: You haven't shown anything or the first part? For the second, try taking $f(x,y) = {|x-y| \over 1-|x-y|}$ on $X=(0,1)$. Note that $f({1 \over 4}, {3 \over 4}) =1$, $f({1 \over 4}, {2 \over 4}) =f({3 \over 4}, {2 \over 4}) = {1 \over 3}$., so the triangle inequality does not hold. Show that $d^*$ as computed above is a metric.

Comment: @copper.hat But will $\sup |f-g|$ be a metric, as I asked in the comments?

Comment: That is not the question you asked above.

Comment: @copper.hat True that I should have done something in the first part. I am comfortable with establishing the inequality. After that $ \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|} \leq \sup [\frac{|h-g|}{1+|h-g|}+\frac{|f-h|}{1+|f-h|}] ≤ \sup \frac{|h-g|}{1+|h-g|}+\sup \frac{|f-h|}{1+|f-h|}]$. Now taking sup over the left hand side establishes it, right?

Comment: @copper.hat I have made it clearer.

Comment: As you pointed out yourself $\sup|f-g|$ might be infinite and hence this is a not well-defined map on the non-negative reals and so it could not be a metric.